Github Python Client getting SSL error in get_repo
I am using Pygithub as github client to get repo.  We are using Github Enterprise and it is SSL secured. For that we have added cert in REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE as pem file. I am using below code to access the github.
from github import Github

# Authentication is defined via github.Auth
from github import Auth

# using an access token
auth = Auth.Token("api token")

# First create a Github instance:

# Public Web Github
g = Github(auth=auth)

# Github Enterprise with custom hostname
g = Github(base_url="https://<my repo>/api/v3", auth=auth)

# Then play with your Github objects:
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name)

# To close connections after use
g.close()

it is giving me below error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:703, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    702 # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 703 httplib_response = self._make_request(
    704     conn,
    705     method,
    706     url,
    707     timeout=timeout_obj,
    708     body=body,
    709     headers=headers,
    710     chunked=chunked,
    711 )
    713 # If we're going to release the connection in ``finally:``, then
    714 # the response doesn't need to know about the connection. Otherwise
    715 # it will also try to release it and we'll have a double-release
    716 # mess.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:386, in HTTPConnectionPool._make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    385 try:
--> 386     self._validate_conn(conn)
    387 except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
    388     # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1042, in HTTPSConnectionPool._validate_conn(self, conn)
   1041 if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1042     conn.connect()
   1044 if not conn.is_verified:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py:414, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
    412     context.load_default_certs()
--> 414 self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
    415     sock=conn,
    416     keyfile=self.key_file,
    417     certfile=self.cert_file,
    418     key_password=self.key_password,
    419     ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
    420     ca_cert_dir=self.ca_cert_dir,
    421     ca_cert_data=self.ca_cert_data,
    422     server_hostname=server_hostname,
    423     ssl_context=context,
    424     tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    425 )
    427 # If we're using all defaults and the connection
    428 # is TLSv1 or TLSv1.1 we throw a DeprecationWarning
    429 # for the host.

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:449, in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    448 if send_sni:
--> 449     ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
    450         sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
    451     )
    452 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    492 if server_hostname:
--> 493     return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    494 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:500, in SSLContext.wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    494 def wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side=False,
    495                 do_handshake_on_connect=True,
    496                 suppress_ragged_eofs=True,
    497                 server_hostname=None, session=None):
    498     # SSLSocket class handles server_hostname encoding before it calls
    499     # ctx._wrap_socket()
--> 500     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
    501         sock=sock,
    502         server_side=server_side,
    503         do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    504         suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    505         server_hostname=server_hostname,
    506         context=self,
    507         session=session
    508     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:1040, in SSLSocket._create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
   1039             raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
-> 1040         self.do_handshake()
   1041 except (OSError, ValueError):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/ssl.py:1309, in SSLSocket.do_handshake(self, block)
   1308         self.settimeout(None)
-> 1309     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1310 finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:486, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    485 try:
--> 486     resp = conn.urlopen(
    487         method=request.method,
    488         url=url,
    489         body=request.body,
    490         headers=request.headers,
    491         redirect=False,
    492         assert_same_host=False,
    493         preload_content=False,
    494         decode_content=False,
    495         retries=self.max_retries,
    496         timeout=timeout,
    497         chunked=chunked,
    498     )
    500 except (ProtocolError, OSError) as err:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:815, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    812     log.warning(
    813         "Retrying (%r) after connection broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url
    814     )
--> 815     return self.urlopen(
    816         method,
    817         url,
    818         body,
    819         headers,
    820         retries,
    821         redirect,
    822         assert_same_host,
    823         timeout=timeout,
    824         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    825         release_conn=release_conn,
    826         chunked=chunked,
    827         body_pos=body_pos,
    828         **response_kw
    829     )
    831 # Handle redirect?

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:815, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    812     log.warning(
    813         "Retrying (%r) after connection broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url
    814     )
--> 815     return self.urlopen(
    816         method,
    817         url,
    818         body,
    819         headers,
    820         retries,
    821         redirect,
    822         assert_same_host,
    823         timeout=timeout,
    824         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    825         release_conn=release_conn,
    826         chunked=chunked,
    827         body_pos=body_pos,
    828         **response_kw
    829     )
    831 # Handle redirect?

    [... skipping similar frames: HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen at line 815 (7 times)]

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:815, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    812     log.warning(
    813         "Retrying (%r) after connection broken by '%r': %s", retries, err, url
    814     )
--> 815     return self.urlopen(
    816         method,
    817         url,
    818         body,
    819         headers,
    820         retries,
    821         redirect,
    822         assert_same_host,
    823         timeout=timeout,
    824         pool_timeout=pool_timeout,
    825         release_conn=release_conn,
    826         chunked=chunked,
    827         body_pos=body_pos,
    828         **response_kw
    829     )
    831 # Handle redirect?

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:787, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    785     e = ProtocolError("Connection aborted.", e)
--> 787 retries = retries.increment(
    788     method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    789 )
    790 retries.sleep()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/GithubRetry.py:201, in GithubRetry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    200 # retry the request as usual
--> 201 return super().increment(method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py:592, in Retry.increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    591 if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 592     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    594 log.debug("Incremented Retry for (url='%s'): %r", url, new_retry)

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<git url>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/user/repos (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [20], line 18
     15 g = Github(base_url="https://<git url>/api/v3", auth=auth)
     17 # Then play with your Github objects:
---> 18 for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
     19     print(repo.name)
     21 # To close connections after use

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/PaginatedList.py:84, in PaginatedListBase.__iter__(self)
     82 yield from self.__elements
     83 while self._couldGrow():
---> 84     newElements = self._grow()
     85     yield from newElements

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/PaginatedList.py:95, in PaginatedListBase._grow(self)
     94 def _grow(self) -> List[T]:
---> 95     newElements = self._fetchNextPage()
     96     self.__elements += newElements
     97     return newElements

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/PaginatedList.py:244, in PaginatedList._fetchNextPage(self)
    243 def _fetchNextPage(self) -> List[T]:
--> 244     headers, data = self.__requester.requestJsonAndCheck(
    245         "GET", self.__nextUrl, parameters=self.__nextParams, headers=self.__headers
    246     )
    247     data = data if data else []
    248     return self._getPage(data, headers)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py:537, in Requester.requestJsonAndCheck(self, verb, url, parameters, headers, input)
    529 def requestJsonAndCheck(
    530     self,
    531     verb: str,
   (...)
    535     input: Optional[Any] = None,
    536 ) -> Tuple[Dict[str, Any], Any]:
--> 537     return self.__check(*self.requestJson(verb, url, parameters, headers, input, self.__customConnection(url)))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py:702, in Requester.requestJson(self, verb, url, parameters, headers, input, cnx)
    699 def encode(input: Any) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    700     return "application/json", json.dumps(input)
--> 702 return self.__requestEncode(cnx, verb, url, parameters, headers, input, encode)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py:799, in Requester.__requestEncode(self, cnx, verb, url, parameters, requestHeaders, input, encode)
    795     requestHeaders["Content-Type"], encoded_input = encode(input)
    797 self.NEW_DEBUG_FRAME(requestHeaders)
--> 799 status, responseHeaders, output = self.__requestRaw(cnx, verb, url, requestHeaders, encoded_input)
    801 if Consts.headerRateRemaining in responseHeaders and Consts.headerRateLimit in responseHeaders:
    802     self.rate_limiting = (
    803         # ints expected but sometimes floats returned: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/pull/2697
    804         int(float(responseHeaders[Consts.headerRateRemaining])),
    805         int(float(responseHeaders[Consts.headerRateLimit])),
    806     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py:833, in Requester.__requestRaw(self, cnx, verb, url, requestHeaders, input)
    831     cnx = self.__createConnection()
    832 cnx.request(verb, url, input, requestHeaders)
--> 833 response = cnx.getresponse()
    835 status = response.status
    836 responseHeaders = {k.lower(): v for k, v in response.getheaders()}

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/github/Requester.py:195, in HTTPSRequestsConnectionClass.getresponse(self)
    193 verb = getattr(self.session, self.verb.lower())
    194 url = f"{self.protocol}://{self.host}:{self.port}{self.url}"
--> 195 r = verb(
    196     url,
    197     headers=self.headers,
    198     data=self.input,
    199     timeout=self.timeout,
    200     verify=self.verify,
    201     allow_redirects=False,
    202 )
    203 return RequestsResponse(r)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:602, in Session.get(self, url, **kwargs)
    594 r"""Sends a GET request. Returns :class:`Response` object.
    595 
    596 :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    597 :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    598 :rtype: requests.Response
    599 """
    601 kwargs.setdefault("allow_redirects", True)
--> 602 return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     "timeout": timeout,
    586     "allow_redirects": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:517, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    513         raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    515     if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    516         # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 517         raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    519     raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    521 except ClosedPoolError as e:

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<git url>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/user/repos (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))

from the same system i can git clone using command.
this setup is working in our other environments as well.

I'm not sure but maybe module doesn't know that you have some REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE as pem file. OR maybe it is only problem with C/C++ module for SSL and it needs to update OpenSSL.
